# Unable to launch web project through dart editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Just starting up on Dart and I am unable to launch web project from dart editor, command line projects work fine.

I get this exception while trying to start web project

Running pub get on C:\Users\Admin\dart\DartABWebApp ... ---
Pub get failed, [69] Resolving dependencies...
Got socket error trying to find package browser at https://pub.dartlang.org.

Anyone knows how to resolve this ?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Some people seem to have issues; see if this info helps: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!topic/misc/YlspV60sd7c

Comment: What Dart version, what OS, how do you launch the web project? Do you have an internet connection?

Comment: Hi I downloaded the latest Dart, Dart Editor version 1.6.0.release. Windows7 64 bit. Yes obviously I do have an internet connection :)

Comment: I moved the installation directly under primary drive and that did the trick. Looks like something is buggy in latest release wrt installation directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the installation directly under primary drive and that did the trick